# Get user detail (name and phone number) from aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using the Cognito hosted UI for login (implicit grant), I am able to login successfully. I received the access token as a hash in the callback URL. How do I extract the token from the URL and get the user details like Name and PhoneNumber?

Note: Not using any SDK

My requestURL is as below
https:///login?response_type=token&client_id=*************&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/searchEvent

Redirected URL is as below

http://localhost:8080/searchEvent#id_token=**************&access_token=************&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

I did go through various forum but no luck.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ is your application?

Comment: You can extract data from the JWT Tokens.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes as of now it's running on localhost.

Comment: @lightyagami, getting the JWT as a **URL Fragment**. Challenge is to access fragment and pass it to my backend (node.js). Once i have the JWT i can use node packages to extract the details. 

From what I researched so far, we can't pass the URL fragment to a backend. it's available only at the client end (browser) which can be accessed via `window.location.hash`. I am looking for a way to pass the fragment to a backend.
Any suggestions on this appreciated!